# Is is possible to send different body content in PHPMAILER?

Tags: php

Is is possible to send different body content in PHPMAILER?

For Example,

I like to send 
`THis is To address" to TO EMAIL ID` and `This is CC ADDRESS" to CC EMAIL ID`. 
I'm using SMTP method.

Please advise.

Comment: Please give any example code for what you're doing with PHPMAILER now

Comment: TO and CC refer to the same "message" so I think it's not possible... AFAIK, why don't you send different emails?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible to use different body texts when sending more than one email.

Judging from your example, however, you want to display a different body text to both the recipient and a carbon-copy address.

**This is not possible.**

It's called a **carbon-*copy*** for a reason: the email contents should be the same as the one being received by the recipient.

If you really want to display different body texts, send more than one e-mail.